# bcp xml not exporting all rows to individual files

Tags: sql, xml, export, bcp

I have a sql query that exports each XML row of a table to individual XML files.  The process works perfectly, except it stops and does not process all rows at once.  I have to change the row number to start where it left off. It will process all the rows with no errors using this procedure, however I would prefer that it process all rows at once. 
This is my query:

```
DECLARE 
@FILENAME VARCHAR(500),
@bcpcmd  VARCHAR(2000),
@RN VARCHAR(10),
@i int;
DECLARE @Table table (RN int, IsDone char(1))
INSERT @Table SELECT RN, 0 FROM [x_rpt].[dbo].[x_abc] WHERE RN>=1 --this is where I update RN to process records where it leaves off--
SET @i=0
WHILE @i<= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Table WHERE IsDone = '0')
BEGIN 
SELECT TOP 1  @RN=RN FROM @Table WHERE IsDone = 0
SET @FILENAME = '"C:\temp\data\abc\Jan_2016_'+@RN+'.xml"'
SET @bcpcmd = 'BCP "SELECT [XML] from [x_rpt].[dbo].[x_abc] WHERE RN='+@RN+'" queryout "' 
SET @bcpcmd = @bcpcmd + @FILENAME + '" -w -T -S "SERVER"' 

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpcmd

UPDATE @Table set IsDone='1' where RN=convert(int,@RN)
SET @i=@i+1

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `CURSOR` based approach:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeDB.dbo.MockUp(RN INT,[XML] XML);
INSERT INTO SomeDB.dbo.MockUp VALUES
 (1,N'<test RN="1"/>')
,(17,N'<test RN="17"/>')
,(-300,N'<test RN="-300"/>');

DECLARE 
@FILENAME VARCHAR(500),
@bcpcmd  VARCHAR(2000),
@rn INT;
DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT RN FROM SomeDB.dbo.MockUp
OPEN c;
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @rn;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS  = 0
BEGIN
    SET @FILENAME = '"C:\SomePath\Jan_2016_'+CAST(@rn AS VARCHAR(MAX))+'.xml"'
    SET @bcpcmd = 'BCP "SELECT [XML] from SomeDB.[dbo].MockUp WHERE RN='+CAST(@rn AS VARCHAR(MAX))+'" queryout "' 
    SET @bcpcmd = @bcpcmd + @FILENAME + '" -w -T -S ' + @@SERVERNAME 

    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpcmd    

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @rn;
END 

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
GO

DROP TABLE SomeDB.dbo.MockUp
```

Adjust path and database / schema / table / column names...

Comment: Is this question solved? It is very kind to say *thank you*, but it would be even kinder of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!